# Perl Error while performing xslt transformation

Tags: xml, perl, xslt

I am trying to perform a simple xml transformation using XSLT 1.0.
Here are my xml and xslt files.

**XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="xsl" href="trans.xsl"?>
<Article>
  <Title>My Article</Title>
  <Authors>
    <Author>Mr. Foo</Author>
    <Author>Mr. Bar</Author>
  </Authors>
  <Body>This is my article text.</Body>
</Article>
```

**XSLT File**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">    
  <xsl:output method="text"/>    
  <xsl:template match="/">
    Article - <xsl:value-of select="/Article/Title"/>
    Authors: <xsl:apply-templates select="/Article/Authors/Author"/>
  </xsl:template>    
  <xsl:template match="Author">
    - <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here is my perl script that I am using.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Std;
use File::Path;
use File::Spec;
use File::Basename;
use Env;
use XML::LibXSLT;
use XML::LibXML;

my %opts = ();
getopts('p:f:'\%opts);

my $xsltfile = $opts{'p'};
die "XSLT file not specified" if !defined($xsltfile);

my $xmlfile = $opts{'f'};
die "XML file not specified" if !defined($xmlfile);

# XSLT Transformation code starts here

#my $xml_parser = XML::LibXML->new();
#my $source = $xml_parser->parse_file($msgcatfile);

my $source = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $xmlfile);

#my $xslt_parser = XML::LibXML->new();
#my $xslt_source = $xslt_parser->parse_file($xsltfile);

my $xslt_source = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $xsltfile);    
my $xslt = XML::LibXSLT->new();

my $stylesheet;

eval { $stylesheet = $xslt->parse_stylesheet($xslt_source); };

if ($@)
{
    print "$@";
    die "\n!******************Error in parsing the stylesheet file : $xsltfile ************************!\n";
}

eval { my $results = $stylesheet->transform_file($source); };

if ($@)
{
    print "$@";
    die "\n!******************Error in transforming the input xml file : $source ************************!\n";
}
print $stylesheet->output_as_bytes($results);
0;
```

I am not sure what is going wrong but when run this perl script, I am getting following errors which I am not able decipher.

```
Bareword found where operator expected at trans.xslt line 2, near ""1.0" xmlns"
        (Missing operator before xmlns?)
Bareword found where operator expected at trans.xslt line 11, near "</xsl"
  (Might be a runaway multi-line // string starting on line 10)
        (Missing operator before l?)
syntax error at trans.xslt line 2, near "xsl:"
Execution of trans.xslt aborted due to compilation errors.
```

I could not find any similar posts (relevant to XML/XSLT) when I searched for keywords in the error message. 
Am I missing something obvious?

**:UPDATE:**

I ran my program as

`perl transform.pl -p trans.xslt -f example.xml`

Comment: How do you run your program? It Looks like you try to run the xsl file with perl.

Comment: You have shown your XSLT file twice. Please show your XML

Comment: The Perl code that you show fails to compile with the message `Global symbol "$results" requires explicit package name`. In fact the line `getopts('p:f:'\%opts)` is also illegal, but I had removed it to facilitate testing. Please show the real code that's giving you this error

Comment: I bet that *is* his code. He's just never got as far as executing it, as (somehow) he's executing the XSLT, not the Perl.

Comment: @DaveCross: Haha that one went over my head!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow you are executing your XSLT file as Perl code, but there is nothing in your question to explain how. In fact, as I commented, the Perl code that you show *cannot* have caused the error you say it did because it won't compile

I can see a problem with the call to `$stylesheet->transform_file($source)`, which should be either `$stylesheet->transform($source)` or `$stylesheet->transform_file($xmlfile)`, but the rest of the bugs are obvious

Note also that the stylesheet attached to the XML document with the `xml-stylesheet` processing instruction is `test.xsl`, whereas your Perl code applies `test.xslt`. You should choose one or the other

Your call to `$stylesheet->output_as_bytes($results)` is better as `$stylesheet->output_as_chars($results)`. It doesn't make any difference with pure ASCII data, but the former will produce encoded octets, which is rarely useful. Usually you just want a character string

It's best to avoid writing fancy parameter input and exception-handling code before you have the basic program working. I suggest you start from my code here instead, and use the [`Try::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Try::Tiny) module instead of a simple `eval` if you must handle the errors. At present, all your handlers seem to do is supplement the exception message with a lot of stars and then die anyway, so I think you can do without them

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXSLT;

my ($xmlfile, $xsltfile) = qw/ example.xml trans.xsl /;

my $xslt = XML::LibXSLT->new;
my $stylesheet = $xslt->parse_stylesheet_file($xsltfile);
my $results    = $stylesheet->transform_file($xmlfile);

print $stylesheet->output_as_chars($results);
```

#### output

```
Article - My Article
Authors: 
- Mr. Foo
- Mr. Bar
```

Answer (score 1):

> Execution of trans.xslt aborted due to compilation errors.

This looks like you're trying to execute your XSLT file, not your Perl program.

You should be running something like this:

```
$ ./your_xslt_processor.pl -f your_xml.xml -p trans.xslt
```