# xsl:copy-of : could not compile select expression

Tags: xml, perl, xslt

I am trying to transform an xml file using xsl stylesheet.

**xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<msg>
    <ent key="key1">
        <text>Error: Could not find </text>
        <translation>Another Error similar to previous one.</translation>
    </ent>
</msg>
```

**xsl file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:template match="msg">
        <xsl:for-each select="ent">
            <xsl:variable name="current_key" select="@key"/>
            <xsl:variable name="Match" select="$translations/msg/ent[@key = $current_key]"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$Match and normalize-space($Match/text) = normalize-space(.) and (not(@translate) or @translate = true())">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$Match/(@key|translation/text())|@context"/>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

`@translate` is one of the attributes but I have not included it in the example xml file.

I am using Perl to do my transformation. 
I use the script as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37727023/1410711), when I get the following error,

```
Invalid expression
compilation error: file test.xsl line 11 element copy-of
xsl:copy-of : could not compile select expression '$Match/(@key|translation/text())|@context'
 at Transform.pl line 10
```

Why is the `select` expression causing problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `$Match/(@key|translation/text())` is allowed in XPath 2.0 as used in XSLT 2.0 but Perl is likely to use an XSLT 1.0 processor like libxslt. So you would need to spell it out as `$Match/@key | $Match/translation/text()`.