# Variable not available from one xsl file to other

Tags: xml, perl, xslt

I am trying to perform XSLT 1.0 transformation using Perl. I am using the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37727023) listed here as my script.

My input xml file looks somewhat like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <bsg>
          <msg>
               <entry key="testingString">This is a test.</entry>
               <!-- <trs> This is me, trs!!! </trs> -->
            </msg>
    </bsg>
```

`trs` attribute is optional meaning its not always present in all other `entry` nodes.
Entry can have optional property `tslate` which can be `true` or `false` i.e input xml file can have something like

`<entry key="Doctor" tslate="false">Physician.</entry>`

To the Perl script, I supply the xslt file which imports two other xslt files (say File A and File B) which has variables and templates defined.

File A reads a node from input xml file as and performs following operation

```
<xsl:param name="isOTHERFILEavailable"/>    
  <xsl:variable name="tvariables">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$isOTHERFILEavailable = 'true'">
        <xsl:copy-of select="document($OTHERTHE_File)/bsg/msg"/>
      </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>
```

`isOTHERFILEavailable` is a string parameter passed from Perl file that validates whether `OTHERFILE` exists or not.

This `tvariables` is then accessed to perform some other operation in File B as below

```
<xsl:template match="msg">
<xsl:variable name="trsExists">
            <xsl:for-each select="entry">
                <xsl:variable name="current_key" select="@key"/>
                <xsl:variable name="trsMatch" select="$tvariables/msg/entry[@key = $current_key]"/>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$trsMatch and normalize-space($trsMatch/text) = normalize-space(.) and (not(@tslate) or @tslate = true())">
                        <xsl:copy>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="$trsMatch/@key|$trsMatch/tvariables/text()|@context"/>                     
                        </xsl:copy>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>        
</xsl:variable>
</xsl:template>
```

My problem is, when I reach this line,

`<xsl:variable name="trsMatch" select="$tvariables/msg/entry[@key = $current_key]"/>`

Perl errors out as following

`Invalid type
runtime error: file B.xslt line # element variable
Failed to evaluate the expression of variable 'tvariables'`

Am I missing something obvious?

P.S => Everything runs fine when run the same transform from Java using XSLT 2.0(Saxon) and even when `tvariables` is not defined, that is when `isOTHERFILEavailable` is `false`.

Comment: what about `$OTHERTHE_File` and `document($OTHERTHE_File)/bsg/msg`, are they sure to be passed and existing? Maybe it's a path issue finding $OTHERTHE_File? Is it a fully qualified path?

Comment: @StefanHegny.. yes, the path supplied is fully qualified path. The `OTHER_File` may not be always present. I wonder why the transformation in java works fine in that case.

Comment: your question title suggests something "from one xslt file to another", are there two xslts involved, how are they "coupled"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$tvariable is a xml fragment.

It seems likely to me that Perl is using a XSL 1.0 Processor.  In which case your problem is that $tvariable will need to be converted froma fragment into a node-set before you can use it.  XSL 2, handles fragments just as you would expect which is why the code runs in Saxon.
Fortunaltely most XSL 1.0 Processors (prehap all?) provide support for fragments with an extension function.  You'll need to check your documentation for the details.
Your select statement will become something like:

```
 select="node-set($tvariables)/msg/entry[@key = $current_key]"
```

Check out http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/07/16/nodeset.html for more info about node-set functions.