# exsl:node-set not retrieving attribute's value

Tags: perl, xslt, exslt

Here is a toned down version of my use case. I have

XSL file for transformation

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="exsl">

<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:template match="Message">
    <xsl:for-each select="ent">
        <xsl:variable name="current_key" select="@key"/>
        <xsl:variable name="current_type" select="@type"/>
        <xsl:variable name="Match" select="exsl:node-set(msg)/ent"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="exsl:node-set($Match)/@type"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="exsl:node-set($Match)/@key|exsl:node-set($Match)/translation/text()"/>
            <!--- <xsl:copy-of select="exsl:node-set($Match)/@key|exsl:node-set($Match)/translation/text()|exsl:node-set($Match)/@type"/>  Trial statement -->
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:call-template name = "Me" select="$Message"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And an input file as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<msg>
    <ent key="key1" type="error">
        <text>Error: Could not find </text>
        <translation>Another Error similar to previous one.</translation>
    </ent>
    <ent key="key2" type="damage">
        <text>Error2: Could not find2 </text>
        <translation>Another Error2 similar to previous one.</translation>
    </ent>
</msg>
```

I am using libXSLT in Perl as my transformation engine. My transformation script is already mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37727023). Whenever I execute the script, I get the output as follows.

```
Error: Could not find 
Another Error similar to previous one.

Error2: Could not find2 
Another Error2 similar to previous one.
```

Why is the attribute `type` not getting printed? How do I retrieve it with the help of `exsl:node-set` or any other techniques? Also, can I include the attribute `type` in the trial statement in such a way that it will be in the output?

Comment: That doesn't fit together, there is no `Message` node on which your template matches in your input at all?! Why are you trying to use `exsl:node-set()` here probably can not be determined without seeing matching xsl and input xml

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying. The script runs fine and template gets called and output is displayed. I dont know how to post a minimal, reproducible and workable example except for this one.

Comment: It may be a default template that produces the output. How do you expect a template matching `Message` being called when there is no element named Message in the input? - Your minimal example may be minimal but it is no longer correct and might not help your real problem

Comment: If I change the `Message` with `/`, I still get the same output. Does the `/` signify the default template?

Comment: @Recker Your stylesheet does not do anything except copy all text nodes to the output. This is done by the built-in templates. Your own template does not match anything in the input and is never executed. -- In addition, there are numerous things in your attempt that make no sense, including your use of `exsl:node-set()`. Please post the expected result of the transformation, so we can show you how to get it.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I had earlier asked this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38007406/1410711) which explains my intent. I just created a smaller version of it. Bottomline, I am not able to print the attributes `key` and `type` and I want to print it .

Comment: **1.** Please make your questions self-contained. -- **2.** Neither this question nor the other one shows the expected output. "*print the attributes*" can be interpreted in so many ways.

Comment: @Recker, no `/` does **not** signify the default template. Default templates are what the xslt processor does when no of your templates match. `/` makes that template match the root of the input document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/msg">
    <xsl:for-each select="ent">
        <xsl:text>KEY: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@key"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;TYPE: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;TEXT: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="text"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;TRANSLATION: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="translation"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your input example, will produce:

```
KEY: key1
TYPE: error
TEXT: Error: Could not find 
TRANSLATION: Another Error similar to previous one.

KEY: key2
TYPE: damage
TEXT: Error2: Could not find2 
TRANSLATION: Another Error2 similar to previous one.
```