# Perl xslt transformation output to file

Tags: xml, perl, xslt, libxslt

I am using this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37727023/1410711) answer to perform XSLT 1.0 tranformation. I intend save the output in another xml file. As such I add,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXSLT;

my ($xmlfile, $xsltfile,$outfile) = qw/ example.xml trans.xsl out.xml /;

my $xslt = XML::LibXSLT->new;
my $stylesheet = $xslt->parse_stylesheet_file($xsltfile);
my $results    = $stylesheet->transform_file($xmlfile);

$stylesheet->output_file($results,$outfile);
```

This produces following error,

```
Can't coerce UNKNOWN to string in entersub at $LongPath/XML/LibXSLT.pm line 485.
```

Looking up online, I was able to find this [blog](http://blog.rlucas.net/ancient/cant-coerce-glob-to-string-in-entersub-means-file-not-found/) which mentions something similar.

Am I missing something obvious?

**UPDATE**

**XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="xsl" href="trans.xsl"?>
<Article>
  <Title>My Article</Title>
  <Authors>
    <Author>Mr. Foo</Author>
    <Author>Mr. Bar</Author>
  </Authors>
  <Body>This is my article text.</Body>
</Article>
```

**XSL File**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">    
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>    
  <xsl:template match="/">
    Article - <xsl:value-of select="/Article/Title"/>
    Authors: <xsl:apply-templates select="/Article/Authors/Author"/>
  </xsl:template>    
  <xsl:template match="Author">
    - <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You're missing a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @choroba Updated the question

Comment: That's not self contained, example.xml and trans.xsl are missing.

Comment: The output file was created, but it's not an XML file.

Comment: Yup, I know that. I have a much bigger use case for which I get the error message. :(

Comment: So try to reduce the bigger use case. Remove unrelated parts until you have the minimal example, or you solve the issue.

Comment: See @Borodin's answer in your earlier question. You are not outputting an XML but a text as there is no root element. Specify text method in `<xsl:output .../>`, transform, and then save result string to file.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the problem myself. It appears that

```
$stylesheet->output_file($results,$outfile);
```

statement was not able to create the file with the path supplied.
This path had few non existent directories. As such I ended up doing

```
my $dir = dirname($outfile);
mkpath($dir);
```

after which I was able to save the output to `$outfile`.